# retrieving the value of div

Tags: asp.net, fckeditor

I am using an empty div in which i am assigning values through an external javascript via ajax call I am also using an fck editor what I want to do using an internal javascript I want to set the contents of that div in the textarea of fckeditor but in the internal javascript when I am accessing the contents of that div then it is showing "undefined".

Comment: have tried innerhtml for getting div data

Comment: yes i tried both innerhtml as well inner text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use setAttribute method to set 'value' attribute of an attribute.

let take an example:

```
<div id="employees">
<div id="george">George Doe: Human resources department</div>
</div>
```

To insert a new DIV directly above "george", so the outcome becomes:

```
<div id="employees">
<div id='kevin">Kevin Lin: Main system administrator</div>
<div id="george">George Doe: Human resources department</div>
</div>
```

You would do the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var newemployee=document.createElement("div")
var oldemployee=document.getElementById("george")
newemployee.setAttribute("id", "kevin")
newemployee.innerHTML="Kevin Lin: Main system administrator"
document.getElementById("employees").insertBefore(newemployee, oldemployee)

</script>
```